# Asking for promotion when manager is leaving

Tags: career-development, promotion

I want to get promoted to the next level up. The person to make that decision is leaving in a few weeks. That manager has already checked out, and is basically counting down the days to the final departure.

For the record, the person above me that I want to replace is completing his term (limited to 5 years in that position, then reverts down to my level again), so I feel it's either promote me or not have any representation here. This is also a *volunteer* organization, so pay is not an issue to me. The type of position I would be taking is necessary, as it eliminates someone traveling 400 km to my location, approximately 3-5 times per year during regular work hours.

Because of the vast distance between everyone, I would be emailing my request in, and following up a few days later with a phone call. According to all the documentation, I meet all the requirements and just need the **OK** to do so. I highlighted on an Email draft that I would be a great fit for the role, as well as my reasons why.

No one knows who will be taking the main manager's place, but I would like to move up *in the interim* to the position just below, which is still a level higher than what I am now. **Would it be OK for me to contact the *current* management to request a promotion, or wait and see who the new manager is?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with talking to the current manager - he may have checked out mentally but as far as you are concerned, he is on duty until the day he leaves.

Let him know explicitly what you want - he is not a mind reader. Once you let him know, he has three options:

1. promote or not to promote you on his own power and responsibility, and after checking with the appropriate third parties.
2. tell you to wait until a new manager comes on board. At which point, you might want to tell him that you are a known quantity to him but you won't be to the next manager. And if he thinks that you're fully capable of doing it, promoting you to that position may be a last favor that he'd be doing for the organization. If he still turns you down, then ask him for a reference that you can use on the new manager, whoever they might be.
3. tell you to someone else in the organization, even though he is still physically on the job. At which point, you should be asking for his backing and support before you talk to that someone else.

Don't let the grass grow under your feet. Talk to him ASAP.

You could make a master argument at this point in the organization's fortunes, it's even more about the need of the organization to have someone with your quals in that position than about your freely admitted desire to be promoted into that position.

Comment: That is some good advice. Thanks! I'll shoot off the email, and see what happens then. This at least gives me a great next-step for whatever may happen.

Comment: Well the message was just sent. Now I play the waiting game. Thanks again for the quick advice

Comment: Cool - In terms of fitness for being promoted, a quick, decisive reaction on your part is part and parcel of the test you have to pass :) Follow up by the middle afternoon of the next day, if you don't hear anything, as time is of the essence.